# why select items are not being populated

Tags: angularjs

Here is my html code

```
<select id="userGroups" name="userGroups" ng-model="userGroups" class="form-control">
    <option value="{{grp.groupId}}" ng-repeat="grp in groups">{{grp.groupName}}</option>
</select>
```

here is my controller

```
function MyController($scope, MYAPI) {
    $scope.groups = MYAPI.GroupList.get();
}
```

Why options are not being popuplated?

Ok I have changed my controller to resolve the GroupList before populating the view, but its still not showing

```
MYApp.controller('CreateUserController', ['$scope', 'groupList', function($scope, groupList) {
    $scope.groups = groupList;
    debugger;   //here I can see groups has objects which I need to display

}]);
```

but still dropdown is not loading...

Comment: Can you post? What are you getting in `$scope.groups`

Comment: Its returning promise.... I checked by placing debugger after .get() line... but it should not automatically update $scope.groups once data is finished loading?

Comment: TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: controller code update but still no results on page... :(

Comment: Add this below select and see what it renders: <pre>{{ groups | json }}</pre>

Comment: its returning {{ groups | json }}

Comment: Then your app is not working properly. Do you have a ng-controller directive somewhere or are you using routes?

Comment: here is complete code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23341302/why-view-is-not-getting-objects-from-scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Martin said you need to use ng-options.

This is how it should look like:

```
<select id="userGroups" 
        name="userGroups" 
        ng-model="userGroups" 
        ng-options="grp.groupId as grp.groupName for grp in groups"
        class="form-control">
</select>
```

Comment: thx for explaining how to set value and text via grp.groupId as grp.groupName

Answer (score 0):

Accorting to the AngularJS [documentation of *select*](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) you have to use `ng-options`. This use case is not supported by `ng-repeat`:

> `ngOptions` provides an iterator facility for the `<option>` element which should be used instead of `ngRepeat` when you want the `select` model to be bound to a non-string value. This is because an option element can only be bound to string values at present.