# Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider

Tags: angularjs

I have app.js code like this

```
var MYApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'myAppServices', 'ngSanitize'])    
    .config(myRouter);


angular.module('myAppServices', ['ngResource'])
    .factory('GridsAPI', function($resource) {
        return {
            Users: $resource('/MY/system/users/grid'),
            Groups: $resource('/MY/system/groups/grid'),
            GroupList: $resource('/MY/system/getGroupList')
        };
    });
MYApp.controller('CreateUserController', ['$scope', 'groupList', function($scope, groupList) {
    $scope.test = 'Hello';
    $scope.groups = groupList;
    debugger;   //here I am getting correct values of test and groups
}]);
function myRouter($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when('/users/create', {
            templateUrl: '/MY/system/users/create',
            controller: 'CreateUserController',
            resolve: {
                groupList: function(GridsAPI) {
                    return GridsAPI.GroupList.get().$promise;
                }
            }
        });
}
```

here is my html

```
<div class="white-box" ng-controller="CreateUserController">
    <h1>{{test}}</h1>
    <pre>{{ groups | json }}
</div>
```

and in browser I am getting this, no binding at all, what I am missing??

```
{{test}} 
{{ groups | json }}
```

at debugger I am getting object correctly... see the screenshot

[image]

Comment: Please show the entire HTML.

Comment: That is the complete html.... also I am getting error Unknown provider: groupListProvider

Comment: What is the error in the Developer Tools console?

Comment: Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$injector/unpr?p0=groupListProvider%20%3C-%20groupList
    at Error (native)

Comment: So, the issue is that Angular cannot resolve the dependency `groupList` on the controller.  Should it be `GroupList`?

Comment: but at debugger line inside controller. I am getting groupList correctly

Comment: Ok found the issue.... I need to remove ng-controller from html file

Answer (score 0):

Your resolve returns a promise. This promise will contain your groups as soon as they arrive.

```
MYApp.controller('CreateUserController', ['$scope', 'groupListPromise', function($scope, groupList) {
    $scope.test = 'Hello';
    $scope.groups = [];
    groupListPromise.then(function(groupList){
       $scope.groups = groupList;
    });
    debugger;   //here I am getting correct values of test and groups
}]);
function myRouter($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when('/users/create', {
            templateUrl: '/MY/system/users/create',
            controller: 'CreateUserController',
            resolve: {
                groupListPromise: function(GridsAPI) {
                    return GridsAPI.GroupList.get().$promise;
                }
            }
        });
}
```